# Ruby match multiple string Regex

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to enhance my script below to print only the unique values that shud be of
*) 6 characters  - alphanumeric and in lowercase or 
*)  words starting with map ,from the list of files in a directory

What I've tried

```
values = []
@files = Dir.glob("*.txt")
for values in @files
 file = File.read(values)
 file.split(' ').each do |line|
    values.push(line.gsub(',', '')) if line.match(/[a-z0-9]{6}/) end or unless values.include? line.gsub(',', '') or line.match(/map_.*/)
  end
end

puts values
```

**Example,**

file 1

```
[id]
col1 = map_dr_check, map_iop, foo123
col2 = bar123, FOO123
col3 = ta2ngo, bar123

[/id_check]
@col2 = dr
@col1 = r
```

file 2

```
[id]
col1 = map_dr_check, map_iop, foo123
col2 = alp23r
col3 = poi90k, bar123

[/id_check]
@col2 = *
@col1 = r
```

Expected output

```
map_dr_check
map_iop
foo123
ta2ngo
bar123
alp23r
poi90k
```

but my output is empty and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong with my regex or whether the .match method is supported with string.

Comment: Oh my what have you done `if line.match(/[a-z0-9]{6}/) end or unless values.include? line.gsub(',', '') or line.match(/map_.*/)`

Comment: @engineersmnky : I'm sorry about the ill formed syntax, Im very new to Ruby and just exploring concepts. Can you please correct me here, thank you.

Comment: new to ruby or new to programming? My reason for asking is if you are coming from another language your conditional is equivalent to `if line.match(/[a-z0-9]{6}/) or (if not(values.include?(line.gsub(',', '') or line.match(/map_.*/))))` which I am sure you would not write anywhere else either. Additionally in ruby one would usually use `||` in place of `or` as it has a different (higher) precedence.

Comment: @engineersmnky :My apologies, new to programming. any help is really appreciated, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
input = ... # get it from files, or whatever
input.split.grep(/\A[[:alnum:]]{6}\z|\Amap_.*/)
```

---

For your example (untested):

```
Dir.glob("*.txt").flat_map do |file|
  File.read(file).split.grep(/\A[[:alnum:]]{6}\z|\Amap_.*/)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking in to this, when I tried your above solution

`Dir.glob("*.txt").flat_map do |file|
 value= file.read(file).split.grep(/\A[[:alnum:]]{6}\z|\Amap_.*/)
 puts value
end`

I'm facing the below error

 **undefined method `flat_map' for #<Array:0x7fc1aa2941b8> (NoMethodError)**

Comment: Upgrade your ruby, `flat_map` is there for ages: https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html